# How to rotateY of this cards using Javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

Hello everyone I am a newbie in development. Can anyone tell me how to rotate its Y-axis on dragging right or left?

I don't know how to do that. Please help me.

I just want whenever I drag it right or left it should slide. I hope you will understand this.

Here is my code

```css
/* @import url(https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Hind+Siliguri:300,600|Martel:400,900); */

@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Nanum+Gothic&display=swap');
* {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  /* font-family:"Hind Siliguri",Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif; */
  font-family: 'Nanum Gothic', sans-serif;
  font-weight: normal;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

header {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
  overflow: hidden;
  background: linear-gradient(to left, #56c1ea, #212529);
  /* background-size: 400%; */
  /* opacity: 0.8; */
  /* background-color:black; */
}

.container {
  overflow: hidden;
  height: 50vh;
  width: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  position: absolute;
  opacity: 0.7;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  /* background-color: blue; */
}

.container>img {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 50vh;
}

.ctn {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  bottom: 20%;
  left: 0;
  display: grid;
  place-items: center;
}

.loader {
  border: 5px solid #f3f3f3;
  /* Light grey */
  border-top: 5px solid #56c1ea;
  /* Blue */
  border-radius: 50%;
  width: 35px;
  height: 35px;
  animation: spin 2s linear infinite;
}

@keyframes spin {
  0% {
    transform: rotate(0deg);
  }
  100% {
    transform: rotate(360deg);
  }
}

.box {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 10%;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  display: grid;
  place-items: center;
  height: 80px;
  /* background-color: blueviolet; */
  overflow: hidden;
  z-index: 1;
}

.box>h1 {
  display: inline-flex;
  place-items: center;
  color: white;
  position: absolute;
  left: 10%;
}

.box>h1>span {
  font-size: 70px;
  color: white;
}

.imgg {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  height: 100vh;
  width: auto;
  z-index: 1;
  transform: rotate(90deg);
}

.searcher {
  position: absolute;
  left: 2%;
  top: 0;
  height: 50vh;
  width: auto;
  /* background-color: blue; */
  overflow: hidden;
  display: grid;
  place-items: center;
  z-index: 1;
}

.searcher .sbox {
  /* background-color: yellow; */
  height: 80px;
  width: auto;
  display: grid;
  place-items: center;
  padding: 5px 25px;
}

.sbox input {
  border: none;
  color: black;
  background-color: white;
  border-radius: 100px;
  padding: 5px 20px;
  width: 400px;
  height: 40px;
}

.sbox h1 {
  color: white;
  font-size: 25px;
}

.sbox .search {
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.sbox span {
  display: grid;
  place-items: center;
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
  height: 100%;
  width: 20%;
  color: #56c1ea;
}

.car {
  position: absolute;
  right: 10%;
  bottom: 0;
  background-color: black;
  overflow: hidden;
  height: 50vh;
  width: 50%;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  min-height: 100vh;
}

.cara {
  position: relative;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
  /* animation: animate 20s linear infinite; */
  transform: perspective(1000px) rotateY(0deg);
}

@keyframes animate {
  0% {
    transform: perspective(1000px) rotateY(0deg);
  }
  100% {
    transform: perspective(1000px) rotateY(360deg);
  }
}

.cara span {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  transform-origin: center;
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
  transform: rotateY(calc(var(--i) * 45deg)) translateZ(400px);
}

.cara span img {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  object-fit: cover;
  /* cursor:pointer; */
  transition: 0.7s;
}

.cara span img:hover {
  transform: scale(1.5);
}
```

```html
<div class="car">
  <div class="cara">
    <span class="slide" style="--i:1;"><img src="../assets/images/1 (1).jpg" alt=""></span>
    <span class="slide" style="--i:2;"><img src="../assets/images/1 (2).jpg" alt=""></span>
    <span class="slide" style="--i:3;"><img src="../assets/images/1 (3).jpg" alt=""></span>
    <span class="slide" style="--i:4;"><img src="../assets/images/1 (4).jpg" alt=""></span>
    <span class="slide" style="--i:5;"><img src="../assets/images/1 (5).jpg" alt=""></span>
    <span class="slide" style="--i:6;"><img src="../assets/images/1 (6).jpg" alt=""></span>
    <span class="slide" style="--i:7;"><img src="../assets/images/default.png" alt=""></span>
    <span class="slide" style="--i:8;"><img src="../assets/images/joker-official-movie-poster-1567011412.jpg" alt=""></span>
  </div>
</div>
```

And also here is its image I want to slide it whenever I drag it left or right.

[image: Here is the image]

Comment: @AHaworth I just want whenever I drag the images right or left it will rotate its Y-axis. You are right when Cara element dragged it starts to rotate I just want that nothing else like goes back to its original position. I have checked all scripts and code on many platforms but I didn't get any right answer for my code please help me.

Comment: H#, I twasa bit unclear what the 'it' is that you want to rotate, but now I've run your snippet I can see that the images are in a circle around a Y axis in 3D so I guess you want the whole lot to rotate left or right about that axis on the user dragging. And that each image should keep its orientation in relation to the other images. Could you confirm that I've understood correctly? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This isn't really a dragging event situation. The carousel is to be rotated if the mouse is down and then moved.

To sense a mouse moving across the carousel (or a touch moving) we have to set up event listeners on it to sense when the mouse is down (or touchstart), the mouse is moved and the mouse is up (touchend).

The carousel transform is set to rotate it an equivalent number of degrees. In this snippet the number of degrees is set as the amount moved (in pixels across the screen) divided by 10 just to dampen it down otherwise it shoots round.

Slides have been given background colors just to make it more obvious what is going on as the code in the question did not include the actual images.

```js
const car = document.querySelector('.car');
const cara = document.querySelector('.cara');
let started = false; //set true when mouse goes down

let degrees = 0; //the number of degrees cara is currently rotated
let lastX;

//The event listeners
function start(e) {
  lastX = e.pageX;
  started = true;
}

function move(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  e.stopPropagation();
  if (started) {
    let newX = e.pageX;
    degrees += (newX - lastX) / 10;//10 is just to dampen down the movement
    cara.style.transform = 'perspective(1000px) rotateY(' + degrees + 'deg)';
    lastX = newX;
  }
}

function stop(e) {
  started = false;
}

car.addEventListener('mousedown', e => { start(e); });

car.addEventListener('mousemove', e => { move(e); });

car.addEventListener('mouseup', e => { stop(e); });

car.addEventListener('touchstart', e => { start(e); });

car.addEventListener('touchmove', e => { move(e); });

car.addEventListener('touchend', e => { stop(e); });
```

```css
/* @import url(https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Hind+Siliguri:300,600|Martel:400,900); */

@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Nanum+Gothic&display=swap');
* {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  /* font-family:"Hind Siliguri",Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif; */
  font-family: 'Nanum Gothic', sans-serif;
  font-weight: normal;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

header {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
  overflow: hidden;
  background: linear-gradient(to left, #56c1ea, #212529);
  /* background-size: 400%; */
  /* opacity: 0.8; */
  /* background-color:black; */
}

.container {
  overflow: hidden;
  height: 50vh;
  width: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  position: absolute;
  opacity: 0.7;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  /* background-color: blue; */
}

.container>img {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 50vh;
}

.ctn {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  bottom: 20%;
  left: 0;
  display: grid;
  place-items: center;
}

.loader {
  border: 5px solid #f3f3f3;
  /* Light grey */
  border-top: 5px solid #56c1ea;
  /* Blue */
  border-radius: 50%;
  width: 35px;
  height: 35px;
  animation: spin 2s linear infinite;
}

@keyframes spin {
  0% {
    transform: rotate(0deg);
  }
  100% {
    transform: rotate(360deg);
  }
}

.box {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 10%;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  display: grid;
  place-items: center;
  height: 80px;
  /* background-color: blueviolet; */
  overflow: hidden;
  z-index: 1;
}

.box>h1 {
  display: inline-flex;
  place-items: center;
  color: white;
  position: absolute;
  left: 10%;
}

.box>h1>span {
  font-size: 70px;
  color: white;
}

.imgg {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  height: 100vh;
  width: auto;
  z-index: 1;
  transform: rotate(90deg);
}

.searcher {
  position: absolute;
  left: 2%;
  top: 0;
  height: 50vh;
  width: auto;
  /* background-color: blue; */
  overflow: hidden;
  display: grid;
  place-items: center;
  z-index: 1;
}

.searcher .sbox {
  /* background-color: yellow; */
  height: 80px;
  width: auto;
  display: grid;
  place-items: center;
  padding: 5px 25px;
}

.sbox input {
  border: none;
  color: black;
  background-color: white;
  border-radius: 100px;
  padding: 5px 20px;
  width: 400px;
  height: 40px;
}

.sbox h1 {
  color: white;
  font-size: 25px;
}

.sbox .search {
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.sbox span {
  display: grid;
  place-items: center;
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
  height: 100%;
  width: 20%;
  color: #56c1ea;
}

.car {
  position: absolute;
  right: 10%;
  bottom: 0;
  background-color: black;
  overflow: hidden;
  height: 50vh;
  width: 50%;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  min-height: 100vh;
}

.cara {
  position: relative;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
  /*animation: animate 20s linear infinite; */
  transform: perspective(1000px) rotateY(0deg);
}

@keyframes animate {
  0% {
    transform: perspective(1000px) rotateY(0deg);
  }
  100% {
    transform: perspective(1000px) rotateY(360deg);
  }
}

.cara span {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  transform-origin: center;
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
  transform: rotateY(calc(var(--i) * 45deg)) translateZ(400px);
}

.cara span img {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  object-fit: cover;
  /* cursor:pointer; */
  transition: 0.7s;
}

.cara span img:hover {
  transform: scale(1.5);
}
```

```html
<div class="car">
  <div class="cara">
    <span class="slide" style="--i:1; background:blue;"><img src="../assets/images/1 (1).jpg" alt=""></span>
    <span class="slide" style="--i:2; background:red;"><img src="../assets/images/1 (2).jpg" alt=""></span>
    <span class="slide" style="--i:3; background:green;"><img src="../assets/images/1 (3).jpg" alt=""></span>
    <span class="slide" style="--i:4; background:magenta;"><img src="../assets/images/1 (4).jpg" alt=""></span>
    <span class="slide" style="--i:5; background:cyan;"><img src="../assets/images/1 (5).jpg" alt=""></span>
    <span class="slide" style="--i:6; background:yellow;"><img src="../assets/images/1 (6).jpg" alt=""></span>
    <span class="slide" style="--i:7; background:purple;"><img src="../assets/images/default.png" alt=""></span>
    <span class="slide" style="--i:8; background:pink;"><img src="../assets/images/joker-official-movie-poster-1567011412.jpg" alt=""></span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you so much brother I really appreciate you. You are so best. I was suffering from this about 2 or 3 months ago, but now my problem has been solved thank you so much.